# How to get real request URL through nginx?

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, servlets

I have a chain tomcat+nginx(with ngx_http_upstream_module).

I've done request.getRequestURL() and I've gotten nginx upstream name instead of real request URL.

How to get real request URL?

Comment: What do you need to be passed, the original URL or the query parameters on the original request?

Comment: The original URL